# Kitchen clambake using kombu?

Tags: kombu

There are special types of seaweed used in a clambake, apparently. I’ve never been to a real one on the shore, so I really don’t know what types are most commonly used.

My question is: can dried kombu be used as the seaweed in a kitchen clambake (basically a seafood boil, except not boiled, steamed)? If yes, does it need to be hydrated before using, or will the steam hydrate it adequately and quickly enough?

Hah, snuck in two questions! Hope that won’t put this question “on hold,” lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use kombu.  I would re-hydrate first, [as these folks do.](https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/home-clambake)